# ZF2 how to call controller object in view file

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have this in my controller and want to use it in view
how to call it from view(index.phtml) file

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel(array('users'=>$userTable->fetchAll()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply in your controller action, return the `ViewModel` instance you just created and in your view file (index.phtml in this case) use it like `echo $this->users` or `echo $users`.